# Fifo Summary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

[image]

My requirement is to find out the stock balance of each item from Mfg Date lot. If we get an order will go with date wise ascending order. For eg If Item A is having 3 mfg date lot and each lot has 5 units , When i get order of 12 units its should run through all lots on ascending order and update the balance of each lot in a column.so here i got order of 12 units so so 1 and 2 lots gets exhausted and balance 2 will be taken form 3 rd lot and the balance 3 should be updated for that row.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I need to do this on SQL

one correction; Order Processed Column is basically the number of units took from the lot

Comment: I am just baffled on what the calculation is.  Sample data as *text* tables would help.  So would an explanation that is consistent with the data being presented.  In particular, the "on stock" quantity changes between rows and it is just unclear what values are used for the calculation.  A database tag is also needed.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff 1 Sorry i couldn't find a way to upload the sample data here. Iam new here. can you help me to do that

Comment: On Stock are the Quantity in my inventory. For each item with different mfg date has different number of Quantity I have in inverntory. That is why its changing

Comment: Underlying logic seems a bit crazy :) I would help with formulating task (if I understand correctly): a) distribute ordered quantity over dates, not using more than stock; b) balance = stock - distributed quantity. Search examples with windowed aggregates, using  `rows preceding unbounded` clause - you should be able distribute everything using set based operations easily.

Comment: yes. its correct. iam finding difficulty in declaring the order quantity as there will be multiple orders

Comment: Is your dataset small enough (maybe 100k rows or fewer) that you could process this with a cursor? It would be less efficient than using window functions but maybe easier to read.

Comment: Yes its less than 100k rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 100k rows a cursor based solution should give reasonable performance, so here's one that produces what you gave as desired output.

If this produces the desired output across your real data, mark this answer as accepted and I'll see if I can figure out a more efficient set based solution to add to this answer.

```
;with cteStock as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A', '2019-10-17', 60, 60)
        , ('B', '2019-09-02', 210, 309), ('B', '2020-03-30', 120, 0)
        , ('C', '2019-03-25', 144, 102), ('C', '2020-03-25', 144, 0)
        , ('C', '2021-03-25', 144, 0), ('D', '2019-02-10', 72, 577)
        , ('D', '2019-02-28', 150, 0), ('D', '2019-03-29', 176, 0)
        , ('D', '2019-11-29', 80, 0), ('D', '2020-01-30', 80, 0)
        , ('D', '2020-04-06', 60, 0)
        ) as Stock (Item, MFGDate, StockQty, OrderQty)
)SELECT *, 0 as OrderProcessed, 0 as BalanceStock
INTO #Stock FROM cteStock
ORDER BY Item, MFGDate

DECLARE @Item nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @ItemLast nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @MfgDate DATE
DECLARE @StockQty INT
DECLARE @OrderQty INT
DECLARE @ResidualDemand INT
DECLARE @OrderProcessed INT
DECLARE @BalanceStock INT
DECLARE @CumeDemand INT
DECLARE curStock CURSOR FOR  SELECT * FROM #Stock ORDER BY Item, MFGDate

OPEN curStock
FETCH NEXT FROM curStock
INTO @Item, @MfgDate, @StockQty, @OrderQty, @OrderProcessed, @BalanceStock
SET @ItemLast = ''
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  BEGIN  
    IF (@ItemLast != @Item) BEGIN --Start a new part
        SET @ItemLast = @Item
        SET @ResidualDemand = 0
    END
    SET @ResidualDemand = @ResidualDemand + @OrderQty
    IF (@ResidualDemand > @StockQty) BEGIN
        SET @OrderProcessed = @StockQty
        SET @ResidualDemand = @ResidualDemand - @StockQty
        SET @BalanceStock = 0
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @OrderProcessed = @ResidualDemand
        SET @ResidualDemand = 0
        SET @BalanceStock = @StockQty - @OrderProcessed
    END
    UPDATE #Stock SET BalanceStock = @BalanceStock, OrderProcessed = @OrderProcessed
    WHERE Item = @Item AND MfgDate = @MfgDate
    FETCH NEXT FROM curStock
    INTO @Item, @MfgDate, @StockQty, @OrderQty, @OrderProcessed, @BalanceStock
END
CLOSE curStock;  
DEALLOCATE curStock;  

SELECT * FROM #Stock

DROP TABLE #Stock
```

I used a temporary table because I don't know if you have access to change the schema,but adding columns for OrderProcessed and BalanceInStock would allow in-place calculation which would be faster. You might even be able to put it in a trigger to automate it.

BTW, I don't know if your situation would allow it, but if you restructured your solution to store QtyProduced instead of QtyInStock it would greatly increase the clarity and efficiency of queries like this. You could define running totals for Produced and Ordered, and a simple difference gives you Backorder and StockOnHand. Plus you could look at production in a specific quarter or year, find extended periods of backlog, etc. You could even make those calculated persisted columns so they were easily available elsewhere.

Your current configuration is difficult to solve because the StockOnHand is not a basic input, it's a system state tangled with the history by a function with discontinuities - each StockOnHand depends on all prior production, all prior orders, and may have hidden backorder that it doesn't show (products with no backorders and products with 100 units backordered both have StockOnHand of zero).

Comment: Thanks @Robert Shehan. It Worked!!

Comment: @SherinNarayanan Great! How is the performance, is it worth looking for a set-based solution or is this fast enough on your system?